# Activerecord validates uniqueness does not work with scope and case_sensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, validates-uniqueness-of

I'm using Rails 7 and I try to [validate the uniqueness of multiple columns](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) using `scope` regardless of the case, as follow:

```
validates :attr1, uniqueness: { scope: %i[attr2 attr3], case_sensitive: false }
```

The following spec passes

```rb
it "is not valid without a unique attr1, attr2, and attr3" do
  model = create(:model)
  expect(build(:model, attr1: model.attr1, attr2: model.attr2, attr3: model.attr3)).to_not be_valid
end
```

But this fails

```rb
it "is not valid without a unique attr1, attr2, and attr3 (case sensitive)" do
  model = create(:model)
  expect(build(:model, attr1: model.attr1.upcase, attr2: model.attr2.upcase, attr3: model.attr3.upcase)).to_not be_valid
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you try to save two instances of the model with attributes:

first instance:
first_name: Frank,
last_name: Smith,
fav_color: Blue

second instance:
first_name: FRANK,
second_name: SMITH,
fav_color: BLUE

and your uniqueness validation on `fav_color` is:

```rb
validates :fav_color, uniqueness: { scope: %i[first_name last_name], case_sensitive: false }
```

The second instance is valid under the case-insensitive uniqueness constraint because the scope is different ("FRANK SMITH" vs. "Frank Smith"). The case insensitivity pertains to the attribute being validated... not the scope.